# Why isn't my bezier curve a curve instead of straight segments?

Tags: bezier-curves, 3d-printing

When I create a bezier curve and start working with it, it's not a curve. As seen here, it's a series of straight segments. When I convert it to a mesh, it still looks like a number of straight segments, like in this photo:

[image]

I have been told this is handled in rendering, but I'm creating objects to use with a 3D printer, so I want the curve to be smooth. What's going on here and what can I do to make my bezier curves actual smooth curves instead of straight segments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It won't be a smooth curve like in a vector software but you can increase the *Resolution* of the curve in the *Object Data* panel:

[image]

This resolution will be taken into account when you'll convert your curve to mesh, the resolution is the number of vertices that will be created between 2 vertices of the curve. For example if I give a resolution of 6 to the default curve, give it thickness with a *Geometry > Bevel > Round* and convert it to mesh, here is what I'll get (and the resolution of the circle profile will be determined in the *Object Data > Geometry > Bevel* panel):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Would you like to increase the resolution value in the curve tab?

[image]

And since the maximum curve resolution is 64, after converting to a mesh, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to add a Subsurface modifier to make the curve smoother more.

---

**Answer to export with subsurface modifier question**
When you export in obj, fbx, stl etc format to send data from blender to external the subsurface modifier can actually transform the mesh. A high subsurface value will make the your file with more triangles. Also if you want to do 3D printing, you will get a smoother surface.

Comment: Does the subsurface modifier work just for rendering, or will that make a difference when I export the mesh as an STL file?

Comment: The subsurface modifier can actually transform the mesh. A high subsurface value will make the STL file with more triangles. You will also get a smoother surface when printing.

Comment: Oh, that's good. Thank you! That's pretty useful. If you want to add that as a sentence in your answer, so it's clear, I'll change my selection for the answer to this one.